# Results and timing table

Tags: php, mysql

So far I've done it with Google spreadsheets, but with some issues with import range and the desire to make it better and more beautiful. Before it looked like this: [Link to Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ah5oq7Dit_Ua9czQENQhxWjkq5095znzYfVZUbPIEcU/edit#gid=1229772185)

I want to do it all with MySQL and PHP.  I've done various tables in the database (tables: user, class, team, time, country).

Now I's so far, that with web form I got finish time to MySQL table with updating status in time table and finish time = on update current_timestamp, I think I have working ranking system as well. Now I am stuck with "time", "differ. leader","diff.rev", and "speed"

Code is so far:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("
   SELECT klass, nimi, synd, teamnimi, start, TIME('finish') AS finish FROM bc2014 T1 
   INNER JOIN bc2014aeg T2 on T1.bc2014_id = T2.bc2014_id
   WHERE klass = 'DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)' ");
```

And:

```
print '<table class="mytable7">';
echo "<tr><th>  Klass DS1 $total_tvp1  </th></tr>";
print '</table>';

print '<table class="mytable7">';
echo "<tr><th>koht </th><th>klass </th><th>Liikme nimi </th><th>Synniaeg</th><th>Tiim</th><th>Start</th><th>Finish</th><th>Time</th><th>Dif.Leader</th><th>Dif.Previous</th><th>km/h</th></tr>";
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($row['synd']);
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>' .$row["ranking"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.removeParanthesis($row["klass"]).'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["nimi"].'  '.$row["Perekonnanimi"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp).'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["teamnimi"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["start"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["finish"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["sum('finish'-'start'something like that"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["difleader"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["difprev"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["speed"].'</td>';
    print '</tr>';
```

and visual:

[image]

I'm trying to get Time, Difeerences speed and place to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically as I can see from your code, you use too much print commands instead of them you can use one print for all of them, in that way you will reduce the load time.
To the question you want to display time dif.leader and rest of them in page?

Comment: @DaerkKnight Yes I want to display them in page

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.time.php

use that to calculate anything you need.

For 'difleader' you might have a seperate query to find and store the leader's time first.

Or you could itarate through your result first, do all the calculations there, then do the output.

**EDIT**:

first you could already calculate the running time in your sql as so:

```
SELECT klass, nimi, synd, teamnimi, start, TIME('finish') AS finish, TIMEDIFF(finish, start) AS runtime
FROM bc2014 T1 
INNER JOIN bc2014aeg T2 on T1.bc2014_id = T2.bc2014_id 
WHERE klass = 'DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)'
ORDER BY runtime desc
```

by ordering your result by the calculated runtime you'll get the leader as your first record.

next you'd iterate through the results and calculate the differences like so:

```
$html="<table>"; // add your table-header here
$firstloop = true;
$km = 4.25;   // for speed-calculation

while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($row['synd']);
    if($firstloop) {
        $leader_runtime = $row["runtime"];
    }
    $html.='<tr>';
    $html.='<td>' .$row["ranking"].'</td>';

    $html.='<td>'.removeParanthesis($row["klass"]).'</td>';
    $html.='<td>'.$row["nimi"].'  '.$row["Perekonnanimi"].'</td>';
    $html.='<td>'.$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp).'</td>';
    $html.='<td>'.$row["teamnimi"].'</td>';
    $html.='<td>'.$row["start"].'</td>';
    $html.='<td>'.$row["finish"].'</td>';
    $html.='<td>'.$row["runtime"].'</td>';

    $difleader = mktime( date('H',$runtime)-date('H',$leader_runtime), date('i',$runtime)-date('i',$leader_runtime), date('s',$runtime)-date('s',$leader_runtime),0,0,0);
    $html.='<td>'. date('H:i:s', $difleader) .'</td>';

    if(isset($prev_runtime)) {  // only show difference if we have a prev_runtime set already
        $difprev = mktime( date('H',$runtime)-date('H',$prev_runtime), date('i',$runtime)-date('i',$prev_runtime), date('s',$runtime)-date('s',$prev_runtime),0,0,0);
        $html.='<td>'. date('H:i:s', $difprev) .'</td>';
    } 
    else {
        $html.= '<td></td>';
    }
    $html.='<td>'.getspeed(timetohours($row["runtime"]),$km).'</td>';
    $html.='</tr>';

    $prev_runtime = $row["runtime"];
    $firstloop = false;
}
$html.="</table>";
echo $html;
```

for speedcalculation write a function like:

```
function getspeed($h,$km) {
  return number_format( $km/$h , 2 );
}
```

with a helper function to calculate the hours out of timestamp:

```
function timetohours($t) {
  return date("G",$t)+(date("i",$t)/60)+(date("s",$t)/60/60);
}
```

Since I don't know what comes from your DB I could not test that,
the time- and speed-calculations are tested.

Comment: @ Jeff An example would be appreciated ;) for 'difleader'

Comment: incredible as a comprehensive response, but seems in Your example some "problems" 
when I just copy paste then in row   '$html.='<td>'.getspeed(timetohours($row["runtime"],$km).'</td>'; ' Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in 
When I write this code out - the seems .removePranthesis problem for table.

Comment: at the base comming "start" as time format " finish" as timestamp
table. Table example is here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwkxk7qb9rrvcq3/Screenshot%202015-04-27%2019.03.44.png?dl=0) - bc2014_id is information about competitor

Comment: I missed a bracket to close timtohours-faunction-call:
getspeed(timetohours($row["runtime"]),$km)

Comment: with this select in phpMyAdmin "finish" value = 00:00:00
 - with this $html. code page can not cope .removeParanthesis($row and
.getspeed(timetohours($row
And I think because finish is 0 the runtime 00:00:00 as well and km/h don't displayd and differ.

Comment: Error when I don't write out .removeParanthesis($row ...
Fatal error: Call to undefined function removeParanthesis() in /home

Comment: where does (or should) the function removeParanthesis() come from?
you could replace it with:
      str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $row["klass"]);

For your problem about 'finish' being 00:00:00 just write a simple if condition to only display that value, diff and speed when 'finish' is greater than 00:00:00

Comment: OK right now I don't know why the finish time don' t displayed, but when I modifyd litlle your timediff in select then I get the runtime result and after thet start working diff. between leader and prev. but all numbers is 23:59:56 [link](http://yx.ee/kliendid/baltosport/kuva/bc2014test.php)
and ok when I fix the removeParanthesis then '$html.='<td>'.getspeed(timetohours($row["runtime"]),$km).'</td>';' in your code gives same error

Comment: seems the diff calculating from sec this 3 hour tifference ..that runingtime 3 hour this calculating minus 3 sec. when was 4 hour then calculating 4 sec.

Comment: Hi, @Jeff Can You look the code again - now after little modification diff leader and diffprev. showing up, but seems calculating is tagled example is [here](http://yx.ee/kliendid/baltosport/kuva/bc2014test.php) and same with speed

Comment: @Margus can you show me the code somewhere? then I could try to figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: Hi @Jeff the code is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tayqgyc08dhp929/result_timing.php?dl=0)

Comment: Hi! @Jeff whether you have had time to look at where it might be a mistake in the code

Comment: Can I get better way to share my code ? - That's You could try to figure out where and what minght be wrong? right now the results is : [link](http://yx.ee/kliendid/baltosport/kuva/bc2014test.php)

Comment: Hi @Jeff  
I dig your example, and .. from where have to come $runtime in '$difleader = mktime( date('H',$runtime)-date('H',$leader_runtime), date('i',$runtime)-date('i',$leader_runtime), date('s',$runtime)-date('s',$leader_runtime),0,0,0); $html.='<td>'. date('H:i:s', $difleader) .'</td>';'

Comment: I Find mistake must by like that 
 $difleader = mktime( date('H',$row["runtime"])-date('H',$leader_runtime), date('i',$row["runtime"])-date('i',$leader_runtime), date('s',$row["runtime"])-date('s',$leader_runtime),0,0,0);
    $html.='<td>'. date('H:i:s', $difleader) .'</td>';

but anyway right now calculating --when difference is 1 hour it's take that like second and when dif. 15 hour it's takes that like 15 second ?!